# Bind Nested Child's Foreground to Parent's Foreground?

Tags: silverlight

I have a datagrid in Silverlight 3.0.

There are three columns in the datagrid.

In the style specified for the datagrid, on mouseover and selected etc., the foreground of the content changes to white.

In the first two columns I have TextBlocks.  Their foreground toggles between black and white.

In the third column, I have a listbox.  The listbox contains dynamic content presented within TextBlocks.

How might I bind the foreground of these TextBlocks such that the foreground is consistent with the foreground for the other columns in the specified datagrid row?

Basically, I want all content in the row to have the same foreground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just setting the TextBlocks background to `Transparent` ?

Comment: TextBlock does not have a Background property.  Also, I am wanting the Foreground property to be set.